# Why arent types passed down when drilling props - react - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a long-time react user but am currently trying to learn Typescript.

In React when you need to prop drill a few levels, why doesn't the type defined in the top level parent stay with the props? Seems frustrating to have to define the type on the parent and all the children the var is passed to.

For example, I define a State variable on the parent and add its type, then I pass it down to the child. On the child props, I will get an error stating: `Binding element 'var name' implicitly has an 'any' type.` So I either need to define the type again on the child, or export the type and import it on the child.

Seems like a lot of extra work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you don't mind, please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does a state type have to do with a prop type? There's no implicit relation between the two so it shouldn't come as a surprise that you need to define either in both places.

If your component is stand-alone, it can be used anywhere by any parent so there's no information for it to glean from any particular parent state.

Centralising your types in their own modules is reasonably common...

```ts
// types.ts

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export type { User };
```

```tsx
// Child.tsx

import type { User } from "./types";

interface ChildProps {
  user: User; // define the prop type
}

const Child = ({ user }: ChildProps) => {
  return <p>Hello, {user.name}</p>;
}

export default Child;
```

```tsx
// Parent.tsx

import type { User } from "./types";
import Child from "./child";

const Parent = () => {
  // use the User type in state
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({ id: 1, name: "Joe" });

  return <Child user={user} />;
};
```

Note that a component's props make up part of its contract. A parent won't be able to use a child without supplying the prop values that satisfy the defined types.